# How do I make this script that heats up my CPU safe

Tags: python, hardware, python-multiprocessing, cpu-usage

I would like to use this script I found to heat up my CPU, however there is no way to safely ensure it doesn't heat up too much.

```
import multiprocessing
import sys

def round_robin_count():
    while(True):
        number = 0
        if(number >= sys.maxsize):
            number = 0
        else:
            number = number + 1


if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == '--about':
    print(__doc__)
elif len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == '--help':
    print('Heater', 'USAGE: python3 ' + sys.argv[0] + ' [option]', sep='\n')
    print('To read about.', 'python3 ' + sys.argv[0] + ' --about' ,sep='  ')
    print('To see this help message.', 'python3 ' + sys.argv[0] + ' --help', sep='  ')
else:
    process_count = 1
    print('Heating up the CPU')
    while(process_count <= multiprocessing.cpu_count()):
        process_to_be_not_seen_again = multiprocessing.Process(target=round_robin_count)
        process_to_be_not_seen_again.start()
        process_count += 1
```

Is [this script](https://gist.github.com/ishan1608/87cb762f31b7af70a867) that's written in Python safe to use to gently warm my computer to expel any bugs? It doesn't seem to have any control over what temperature to hover at, if such a thing were even possible (or safe). If it's not safe, can it be made safe?

Comment: @AriVictor Good general advice, but I don't eat around my computer. I keep it clean.  On rare occasion, I find ants near doors and windows in my house. They get in through small holes that I haven't found a way to plug up. From what I've read, ants just like to explore anywhere they wander (into my house and elsewhere), especially small enclosed areas. If they wander into my computer, and I happen to turn it on while they're inside, they'll come out due to the heat (again, this isn't too often).

Comment: Regardless, you dont want them nesting in there, they can bridge circuits and cause damage that is just annoying. So maybe find a more permanent solution, as running that script will work but its super harmful and dangerous to overload your CPU to heatup just to shoo some bugs. If you run it, make sure you know how to kill it in case your temp gets too hot.

Comment: @AriVictor Although I don't think ants would nest in my laptop in my personal situation (I move it around often, there's no exposed food for them in my house to eat, and they are usually scouting around...eventually to return to the established nest that they came from), it certainly could be possible in a future reader's case. Just surveying with a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=ants+in+computer), many people have this issue. So since I'm wondering about the safety, maybe this is more of a hardware question. I suppose that's why I'm being downvoted. Sorry - I'm new here...

Comment: Not having a go at you, if you asked specifically about the script itself you may have got more responses. Will this heat up your CPU? yes. Is that safe? No... So I'm only suggesting that maybe find a better alternative.

Comment: @AriVictor I asked if it was safe -- and if it's not, if it could be made safe. Perhaps a module that monitors internal temperature could be imported and used to turn it off once it reaches a certain temperature. Should I directly copy and past the script? Everything else in the script seems to work well.

Comment: Yeah, SO prefers when the focus is on the code. If you post the script, describe your intent "I need it to switch off after X minutes, or after reaching X deg C in temperature".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192997/discussion-between-i-dont-code-and-ari-victor).

Comment: Is this The Onion Edition of Stack Overflow…?

Answer (score 3):

To make the script safe I recommend setting a cut off temperature for your CPU. You can check the temperature of your CPU using Pythons inbuilt `psutil`

```
import psutil
print(psutil.sensors_temperatures())
```

output:

```
{'coretemp': [shwtemp(label='Package id 0', current=55.0, high=82.0, critical=100.0), shwtemp(label='Core 0', current=35.0, high=82.0, critical=100.0), shwtemp(label='Core 1', current=34.0, high=82.0, critical=100.0), shwtemp(label='Core 2', current=55.0, high=82.0, critical=100.0), shwtemp(label='Core 3', current=34.0, high=82.0, critical=100.0), shwtemp(label='Core 4', current=35.0, high=82.0, critical=100.0), shwtemp(label='Core 5', current=34.0, high=82.0, critical=100.0)]}
```

So you would need to write a script that can reference this and to make sure no cores are reaching critical temperatures.

So maybe during the while loop, you could ammend it so

```
critical_temp = 80.0
keep_heating = True
cpu_temperatures = psutil.sensors_temperatures()

for cpu_temp in cpu_temperatures['coretemp']:
   if cpu_temp >= critical_temp:
       keep_heating = False
```

Then the while loops could include `keep_heating` as a condition.

```
while process_count <= multiprocessing.cpu_count() and keep_heating:
    process_to_be_not_seen_again = multiprocessing.Process(target=round_robin_count)
    process_to_be_not_seen_again.start()
    process_count += 1
    some_function_to_recheck_heat()
```

Probably add a function to kill the processes as well.

Comment: Thank you for this - I didn't know about psutil. As a caveat, psutil.sensors_temperatures() only appears to work on Linux and FreeBSD, evidently: https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.sensors_temperatures

Comment: You can also find plenty of packages for python that revolve around getting the CPU temp, probably in a better format than psutil anyway

Answer (score 2):

a simple closed-loop controller that works for me just busy loops checking the temperature

start by pulling in some useful libraries and defining a helper:

```
from random import random
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
from psutil import sensors_temperatures

def cpu_temps():
    return sensors_temperatures()['coretemp']
```

I then define a function that does the work and sleeps when CPUs are "too hot" (as defined by `target_temp`):

```
target_temp = 66  # or min(t.high for t in cpu_temps())

def warmer(i):
    while True:
        cur_temp = max(t.current for t in cpu_temps())
        if cur_temp > target_temp:
            sleep(1 + random() * i)
```

the `1 + random() * i` is there to help prevent all CPUs from being spun up when the temperature drops below the target by a small amount

I then wrap it up by abusing a `Pool` from `multiprocessing` so it can do all the work of setting up processes and tearing them down cleanly:

```
print('sensor names:', ', '.join(t.label for t in cpu_temps()))

nprocs = cpu_count()
with Pool(nprocs) as pool:
    jobs = pool.imap(warmer, range(nprocs))

    while True:
        print('current temps:', ', '.join(f'{t.current:.0f}' for t in cpu_temps()))
        sleep(1)
```

this will obviously print out the current temps every second, but could be changed or made into a command line argument with something like [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html)